# Min number of tiles required for a floor

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn how to program in python and I came across this problem that I can only use these functions:

- Basic mathematical and logical operators (+.-, *, /, //, %, **, <. <=, >, >=, ==, !=, and, or, not)
- Any functions and constants available in the Math module
  min, max, abs,
- type
- len (for length of strings)
- int, str, float conversion functions
- round

I'm not looking for an answer more so just how to approach the problem.

The question asks to determine the minimum number of identical tiles all with the same orientation that are required to cover the floor of a rectangular room. Any excess from a tile exceeding the floor area is discarded and cannot be
reused. Write a Python function called min_tiles which consumes 4 positive integers, room_width, room_length, tile_width, tile_length, and produces the
minimum number of tiles required to completely cover the floor of the room.

Here are some examples:

min_tiles(4,4,2,2) => 4

If the tiles are rectangular, they can only be oriented in one direction, not
both. So, if the floor is 3 x 4, and the tiles are 1 x 3, then in one direction it would take 6 tiles to cover the floor (discarding excess pieces), but in the other direction it would only take 4 tiles to cover the floor. You should produce the minimum in this case, which would be 4. Hence min_tiles(3,4,1,3) => 4

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to use a dynamic programming solution to solve this problem, but if you are new to programming in general this would be difficult. You can assume that you would start by placing a tile aligned with a corner of the floor (with two possible orientations), and once this tile is placed it creates two sub-problems of smaller rectangles.

You also know that you can produce `n(l) x m(w)` and `n(w) x m(l)`  rectangles using your one tile with `l x w`. I think the largest (by area) such rectangle that completely fits within the boundaries will always be part of the solution. Maybe try to see if you can prove that is always the case?

Comment: ... I don't have enough reputation to comment on other answers. @Miloslav your code fails on `min_tiles(2, 4, 1, 3)`. @Joran your answer doesn't account for discarding excess.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use dynamic programming the only things we are allowed to use are the functions listed in the question. And yes I think I get what you are trying to explain in your 2nd paragraph I'll try that.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was allowed. Dynamic programming would mean that you store some Array-like structures of values, but you aren't using any mathematical functions outside of basic arithmetic and min/max.

Answer (score 0):

```
def min_tiles_horizontal(room_width,room_length,tile_width,tile_length):
  return math.ceil(room_width / float(tile_width)) * math.ceil(room_length / float(tile_length))

def min_tiles(room_width,room_length,tile_width,tile_length):
  return min(
      min_tiles_horizontal(room_width,room_length,tile_width,tile_length),        
      min_tiles_horizontal(room_width,room_length,tile_length,tile_width))
```

`min_tiles_horizontal` only computes the number of tiles needed if the tiles are oriented horizontally. In `min_tiles` we call the `min_tiles_horizontal` twice - once for getting the number for horizontal tiling and once for getting the number for vertical tiling (we get this by switching `tile_length` and `tile_width` as the arguments) - and we return the minimum of those two numbers.

`float` is used to do a floting point division, e.g. for 3 / float(2) we'll get 1.5 (without using `float` we'd make an integer divide and we'd get 1). `math.ceil` is then used to round the number to the closest greater number, e.g. `math.ceil(2.1)` will give us 3, since when you need 2.1 tiles, you have to use 3.

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain the thought process? I'm not sure why you used float and math.ceil? Im guessing this is part of the answer and I would have to write a similar function for vertical?

Comment: I don't know if it's different which each python version but I have 3 and when I don't use float is the division I still get a float so 3/2 would still give me 1.5 so I guess that part of the code wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yes, in Python3 3/2 == 1.5, in Python 2.7 3/2 == 1. So you can ommit the float function, but if you leave it in, it will work in both versions.